# Excel input pop up box if cell is false

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make an excel worksheet to suit my needs of making word documents (mail merge).

Can I use `IF` function like this:

```
IF(A1=Specific text;Write this text;RUN MACRO with popup box to input other text)
```

Basically, if value is true - write pre defined text and if it is false - give me pop up box to input new text?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, however I would not recommend it because each time the worksheet is calculated, if the result of your `IF()` statement is `FALSE`, the InputBox will be displayed.

However if you insist, try something like the following:

Cell Formula `=IF(A1="Something","Result1", AskForResult())`

In a Code Module, add the following:

```
Public Function AskForResult() As String
    Dim strUserResponse As String

    strUserResponse = InputBox("What result to give?")

    AskForResult = strUserResponse
End Function
```

This will display an InputBox like below when the value in A1 <> "Something"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a vba function you can. If your vba function was:

```
function test() as string

    Test = Inputbox("Enter value")

End function
```

Usage:

```
=if(A1="value", "value1", test)
```